# how to access 2D matrix in a multi-dimension Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix

I have a multi-dimensional matrix in OpenCV, for example like

```
Mat matrix(1,1,CV_64FC(100), Scalar(0));
```

I know it is very easy to access the 2d matrix in a multi-dimension matrix in Matlab, for example like matrix(:,:,1), matrix(:,:,100). But how should we do this in OpenCV? It's true that OpenCV can use at to access one element in the matrix, but how can we access a 2d matrix while fixing the channel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be the following

```
Mat matrix(1,1,CV_64FC(100), Scalar(0));

cv::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(matrix,channels);
int i = 0;
cv::Mat channel_i = channels[i];
```

Pleae see docs [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) and maybe for more advanced manipulation [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels). (not used mixChannels myself)

Answer (score 1):

Note there is difference between a multi-Channel Matrix and a multi-dimensional Matrix in OpenCV.

If you are interested in the latter here is an example that shows how to access each dimension for a [3d Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938681/3481173)